# Why does it say "Invalid Character" under my operators?

Tags: java

Why does it say "Invalid Character" under my operators? 
I'm trying to return the area for my triangle, so I used this equation.

```
public double getArea() {

    double x = (getSide1() + getSide2() + getSide3()) /2;

    double answer = x - ­ getSide1();

    answer = answer * x;

    answer = answer * (x - ­getSide2());

    answer = answer * (x ­- getSide3());

    answer = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(answer));

    return answer;

}

public void setArea(double area) {

    this.area = area;

}
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript, but it is Java.

Comment: There's no operator after `x`. That's why.

Comment: What IDÉE are you using? This is certainly because of the use of a sign other than the minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

This is Java, not JavaScript. There's no operator after `x`. That's why. Moreover, this looks more like an **encoding problem**, as the character of `-` is not the same as `—`.

```
public double getArea() {
    double x = (getSide1() + getSide2() + getSide3()) /2;
    double answer = x -­ getSide1();
    answer = answer * x;
    answer = answer * (x -­ getSide2());
    answer = answer * (x ­- getSide3());
    answer = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(answer));
    return answer;
}

public void setArea(double area) {
    this.area = area;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that must have been a copy and paste error. I edited it just now, so that's the actual code. The subtraction operator was supposed to be there.

Comment: @Nicole Where exactly is it throwing the error?

Comment: Under all of the - signs.

Comment: @Nicole I know why. Copy and paste my answer and check.

Comment: @Nicole Can you check my updated answer, and try and tell me if that works?

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you. What was the difference between my code and your code, though?

Comment: @Nicole I have explained at the very beginning of the answer. Have a look. `:)`

Comment: This just looks like a Typo, not an encoding problem. I voted to close this question.

Comment: @YassinHajaj This is not a typo. I clearly have explained the issue in my answer. Did you even check it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have checked it and also have seen many other posts being closed for the exact same problem.

Comment: @YassinHajaj OKay then. Fine. No worries. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar PS : closed by Jon Skeet himself

Comment: @YassinHajaj Wow!!! `:O` Jon Skeet! `:P`